# How to remove the superfluous empty line before the list environment?

Tags: lists, enumitem

I want to put the section title in the left margin using `titlesec`. However, it results to a superfluous empty line when using `list` environment. How should I remove it without using `vspace`?

Minimal example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  a4paper,
  top=2cm,
  bottom=2cm,
  left=4.5cm,
  right=1.5cm,
}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[leftmargin]{\large\scshape\sffamily}{}{0cm}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{2.5cm}{2ex}{0.5cm}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\section{Section A}

This line is aligned with the section title.

\blindtext

\section{Section B}

\begin{itemize}[nosep]
  \item This line is not aligned with the section title.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: The space comes most likely from the `itemize` environment. You could have a look at the `enumitem` package which controles the shape of this kind of environment: https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem?lang=de

Comment: Sorry, overseen it's already in... Early morning...

Comment: Did you try `[nosep,topsep=0pt]` or some other value?

Comment: @AndiW, `[nosep,topsep=0pt]` does not work. Neither does any other `enumitem` option I have tested.

Comment: the problem is that environments change the mode LaTeX is in - vertical or horizontal. The most easy "workaround" - but no real solution - is to add text before the `itemize` environment if you can. If you can't there still is `\vspace` which is not good practice. Since I have no running LaTeX at the moment I can't really test... Searching `itemize leavevmode` on text.SE looks promising to me - you should find similar questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the beginning of `itemize` like this:

```
\begin{itemize}[nosep,before=\leavevmode\vspace*{-1\baselineskip}]
```

I added option `showframe` and a little bit text to get rid of possible problems caused by `\blindtext` direct before `\begin{itemize}`.

Please see the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{%
  a4paper,
  top=2cm,
  bottom=2cm,
  left=4.5cm,
  right=1.5cm,
  showframe % <=========================================================
}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[leftmargin]{\large\scshape\sffamily}{}{0cm}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{2.5cm}{2ex}{0.5cm} 

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}

\section{Section A}

This line is aligned with the section title.

\blindtext

Some text to get rid of blindtext.

\section{Section B}
%This is some text. 

\begin{itemize}[nosep,before=\leavevmode\vspace*{-1\baselineskip}] % [nosep]
  \item This line is not aligned with the section title.
  \item second item. second item. second item. second item. second item. 
     second item. second item. second item. second item. second item. second item. 
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  a4paper,
  vmargin=2cm,
  left=4.5cm,
  right=1.5cm,
}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[leftmargin]{\large\scshape\sffamily}{}{0cm}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{2.5cm}{2ex}{0.5cm}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\section{Section A}

This line is aligned with the section title.

\blindtext

\section{Section B}

\begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt, before =\leavevmode\vspace*{-\baselineskip}]
  \item This line is aligned with the section title.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]