# Align bibliography from biblatex with leftmargin section headings from titlesec

Tags: biblatex, spacing, titlesec, enumitem

I want to align the bibliography produced by `biblatex`'s `\printbibliography` with a `leftmargin` section (as defined by the `titlesec` package).

Even if I change `\topsep` and `\partopsep` to negative values via `\defbibenvironment`, I cannot get the bibliography to align with the section heading.

This is the result I get:

[image: Resulting document with publications misaligned]

How can I make the first publication start in line with the "Publications" heading, just like "Dolor sit amet" is in line with "Lorem ipsum"?

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{author2019,
  author = {Author, Anne},
  date = {2019},
  title = {A Title},
  journaltitle = {Fancy Journal},
  volume = {1},
  number = {1},
  pages = {350--370}
}
@article{author2020,
  author = {Author, Anne},
  date = {2020},
  title = {A Title},
  journaltitle = {Fancy Journal},
  volume = {1},
  number = {1},
  pages = {350--370}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[
  top=0.25in,
  bottom=0.25in,
  right=0.25in,
  left=1.375in]{geometry}

\usepackage{parskip}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}[leftmargin]
  {\Large\scshape\raggedright}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {}

\titlespacing{\section}
  {8pc}
  {1ex plus .1ex minus .2ex}
  {0pc}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list{}
    {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
     \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
     \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
     % Setting these two negative values decreases the spacing somewhat, but not enough
     \setlength{\partopsep}{-30pt}%
     \setlength{\topsep}{-30pt}%
     \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
{\endlist}
{\item}

\begin{document}

\section{Lorem ipsum}

Dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris quis ligula arcu.

\section{Publications}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=none]

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\printbibliography` is essentially a list. The same effect can be observed when a `\section` starts with an `itemize` or `enumerate`. Of course that doesn't really help finding the issue, but it may give an idea where to look.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/476883/32888. It suffices to just add `\leavevmode\vspace*{-1\baselineskip}` before `\list` in `\defbibenvironment`, as suggested in answers to the linked question.